# Splitting C++/CLI code between .h and .cpp file

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, windows-forms-designer

Is it possible to split a form class code between .h and .cpp file in C++/CLI like we do with native C++

When I do that I get parse error in the designer view.

Comment: Of course, you are doing it wrong.  We can't see you doing it wrong.

Comment: I know that am doing it wrong. that's why i asked here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

Let the method definition in header, for example the constructor and destructor:

```
Form1(void);
~Form1();
```

and create a .cpp file, or just edit an existing : include `"formName.h"` (dont forgot namespace), next:

```
Form1::Form1(void)
{
    // ...
}

Form1::~Form1()
{
   // ...
}
```

For events (Click, Load, etc) load the event, keep definition of method in header and put the implementation in source file.

.h:

```
System::Void Button_Click(System::Object ^sender, System::EventArgs ^e);
```

.cpp:

```
Void Button_Click(Object ^sender, EventArgs ^e)
{
    MessageBox::Show("Hello, world !");
}
```

Comment: Thanks ArthurCPPCLI, what about the InitializeComponent()? Whenevr I move that to cpp I get my designer view corrupted. Does editor expect that InitialiseComponent() to be in .h file

Comment: You put InitializeComponent in FormName.cpp (above main function) ? It works with VC++ 2005 (I have only this version for the moment)

Comment: I move the "InitializeComponent()" method to a cpp file, and add some buttons on the main form, the initialization code for new buttons can be correctly added to the  InitializeComponent() method. Which version of Visual C++ do you use ?

Comment: Hi Arthur, After moving each function one by one, its working now. Thanks for your help